# Drag and Drop Javascript saving position Items after moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm using the dragula Drag and Drop javascript: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dragula/3.0.3/dragula.min.js

All i want is whenever the user changes the positions of the blocks i need to somehow save them and whenever the page is refreshed i display it like he selected it list time i think it's called callback or something.

HTML:

```
    <div id="dragAndDrop">
    <div id="p1" class="dragDropBlock" runat="server">
        <div class="metro landingAccountContainer">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-max">
                <img src="hello.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    <div id="p2" class="dragDropBlock" runat="server">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-max">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 clearPadding">
                <img src="hello.gif" />
            </div>


            <div class="clearBoth"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="p3" class="dragDropBlock" runat="server">
        <div id="phBenefsAndFavorits">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img src="hello.gif" />
            </div>
            <div class="clearBoth"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    <div id="p4" class="dragDropBlock" runat="server">
        <div id="phCustom_1" runat="server" class="dd" visible="false">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <img src="hello.gif" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript function that makes drag and drop available:

```
var containers = $("#dragAndDrop").toArray();
    dragula(containers);
```

On page_Load i have this code:

```
Hashtable dashboardPosition = new Hashtable();
        dashboardPosition.Add("p1",4);
        dashboardPosition.Add("p2", 3);
        dashboardPosition.Add("p3", 2);
        dashboardPosition.Add("p4", 1);

        p1.Attributes.Add("data-index", dashboardPosition["p1"].ToString());
        p2.Attributes.Add("data-index", dashboardPosition["p2"].ToString());
        p3.Attributes.Add("data-index", dashboardPosition["p3"].ToString());
        p4.Attributes.Add("data-index", dashboardPosition["p4"].ToString());
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "YourUniqueScriptKey", "sortDragAndDrops();", true);
```

This is my javascript function that i execute on page_load:

```
function sortDragAndDrops() {
        $('#dragAndDrop').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.append($this.find('.dragDropBlock').get().sort(function (a, b) {
                return $(a).data('index') - $(b).data('index');
            }));
        });
    }
```

I have something like this for you to better understand:
https://jsfiddle.net/qoaqba62/2/

If someone has an answer with another Javascript that does the drag and drop and somehow i can save the positions it is fine too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can save the positions in a database using AJAX and then you display them making use of that.

Comment: You can try to save position in localStorage.

Comment: @jcubic, your solution works too, but what happens when a user clears the localStorage?!

Comment: @Ionut the same that will happen if the app will try to append to div that was removed by user in developer tools.

Comment: But how would i save it in the databse or even in the localStorage? Can i save it in Session State?

Comment: @S.Maia, localStorage is a very simple approach, you can store anything as a string in there.You can find a start point here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp. Saving in the database is a little more tricky but not that hard to do. As I said above, use AJAX to save them and retrieve the positions using JSON.